# How to set index of UIViewController as background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I'm trying to set background to the entire app from the code:

```
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background@2x.png"]]; 

    self.window.rootViewController = controller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the Storyboard I have a simple button in the main UIViewController. In the AppDelegate.m I set that code above, but, I background has added, they is in front of the text that is in the Storyboard.

I want to know how can I set that background from the current index to the last index in the stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subview, set the background image in that subview, frame it to the right size and then send that subview to a position "behind" everything else:

```
[mainView addSubview:backG1];
[mainView sendSubviewToBack:backG1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, wenn you use a storyboard at all, AND declare it in your project settings as THE storyboard of your app, then you are not supposed to create and set the root view controller in your app delegate.

Both of them is perfectly fine, but one is the interface builder/storyboard option and the other is the programmatical way. Both ways just don't agree!!!

If you want to go for storyboards, which I encourage you to do, then give your root view controller an ID and in aoru ypp delegate method didFinishLoadingWithOptions: fetch it from the storyboard and set its background view then.

Have in mind: When you use a background view then you need to set all the background colours of all your view items (that may be tables, table cells, cell content views etc. pp.) to clearColor.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an initial view controller in code (in AppDelegate.m, under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), then it overrides the root view controller in your storyboard.

You can either set your view controller's background in the storyboard, or initialise it like you did - but then you need to create all other UI elements in code as well.